# Taylor's theorem bounded derivatives

Tags: analysis

An infinitely differentiable function f : R → R satisfies the differential equation

$f^3(x) = f(x)$
and the conditions $f(0) = 1, f'(0) = f''(0) = 0.$
If $R > 0$ and $j$ is a positive integer, explain why we can find an $M_j$ such that
$|f^j(x)| < M_j$ for all $x$ with $|x|< R.$

Explain why we can find an M such that
$|f^j(x)| < M$
for all $x$ with $|x| < R$ and all non negative j.

I've been thinking about this but can't establish why the derivatives of f have to be bounded, could anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by $f^3$ ? $f \circ f \circ f$ or $f^{(3)}$ (third derivative) or... $f(x)^3$?

Comment: @JeanMarie Since he specifically said "the differential equation $f^3(x)=f(x)$", it would be natural to assume that it's the third derivative of $f(x)$. One would usually write this $f'''(x)$ or $f^{(3)}(x)$, but i don't see how it is difficult to interpret. The fact that he supplied initial values for $f(0),f'(0)$ _and_ $f''(0)$ makes this a non-issue in my book. It's not the standard notation, but it really cannot mean anything else.

Comment: Sorry I tried to do f^(3) but I didn't know how to code it properly

Comment: @Proxy123 You use curly braces: `f^{(3)}` produces $f^{(3)}$. This has the effect that if you ever want to write curly braces, you need to add backslashes: `\{x\}` makes $\{x\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existence of an $M_j$ such that $\mid f^j(x)\mid\le M_j$ for $\mid x\mid<R$ is simply given by continuity: since $f$ is infinitely differentiable every $f^j$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and thus bounded on $[-R;R]$.

The second statement is true because inductively $f^{3k+j}=f^j$ and thus it suffices to take $M=\max{(M_0, M_1, M_2)}$.

I'm probably missing something, but right now I don't see what to explain further.